# Laravel Login with outside data

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-4

I'm using laravel. I know it has a functionality to do login really easy. But, as far as I know it just work with the laravel database. However, I have the database outside of my server so I am using an API to get everything I need. My question is how can I still use the Authentication function using my API?

It is really easy to connect to the API and check if the user and password match, but after that How can I keep using the auth function of laravel for logout, guest and auth pages, etc.

Other example that may work if it is easier to you understand it that way is imagine that I have my users on a text file instead on a database.

Please help me and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `Auth::login($user);` to simply do it after verifying credentials using API

Comment: But I don't have any user on my database. So, what should be the content of `$user`? And can I define roles like admin or create other with that? @AngularDev

Comment: what is the design of your app then? where you will login the user? on which basis you will define rule?

Comment: I would suggest create one user table at your end also just to store the user info like role,name etc.

Comment: Let's see. So, can I put on `$user` the id i am getting from the API and the user will be logged in? @AngularDev

Comment: No Make users table in your database and check upon each request that if the details given by API not exists in your local User table then insert into users table else just log in the user

Comment: Better use `Auth::loginUsingId($id);` if you want to logg in user just by using ID